# Linked list implementation in c without using double-pointer

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I have implemented a simple linked list in C language, but can it be implemented without using double-pointer(**).I want to implement same program by using only single pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};


void push(struct node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    struct node* new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->data  = new_data;
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
}



void append(struct node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    struct node* new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *last = *head_ref;  /* used in step 5*/
    new_node->data  = new_data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    if (*head_ref == NULL)
    {
       *head_ref = new_node;
       return;
    }
    while (last->next != NULL)
        last = last->next;
    last->next = new_node;
    return;
}

void printList(struct node *node)
{
  while (node != NULL)
  {
     printf(" %d ", node->data);
     node = node->next;
  }
}
int main()
{
  struct node* head = NULL;
  append(&head, 6);
  push(&head, 7);
  push(&head, 1);
  append(&head, 4);
  printf("\n Created Linked list is: ");
  printList(head);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to replace "struct node** head_ref" with "struct node* head_ref"?

---

### Changed code after suggestions(still not getting output)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};


struct node* push(struct node* head, int new_data)
{
    struct node* new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->data  = new_data;
    new_node->next = head;
    head   = new_node;
    return head;
}

struct node* append(struct node* head, int new_data)
{
    struct node* new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *last = head;  /* used in step 5*/
    new_node->data  = new_data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
       head = new_node;
       return head;
    }
    while (last->next != NULL)
        last = last->next;
    last->next = new_node;
    return head;
}


void printList(struct node *node)
{
  while (node != NULL)
  {
     printf(" %d ", node->data);
     node = node->next;
  }
}

int main()
{
  struct node* head = NULL;
  head= append(&head, 6);
  head=push(&head, 7);
  head=push(&head, 1);
  head=append(&head, 4);
  printf("\n Created Linked list is: ");
  printList(head);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you use your function result for something besides `void`, sure.

Comment: Sure - return the head as a function result instead of all those voids

Comment: @WhozCraig only one of us should be on this tag at time:)

Comment: using a sentry-node would simplify this, see [here](http://pastebin.com/HC1DLK4M)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can rewrite this code using only single pointers, but you would have to change the semantic of your API and the pattern in which it is used.

Essentially, you replace the second level of indirection in

```
void push(struct node** head_ref, int new_data)
```

with a client-side assignment, i.e.

```
struct node* push(struct node* head, int new_data)
```

This means that instead of

```
push(&head, num);
```

the caller will have to write

```
head = push(head, num);
```

Same goes for the implementation of `append`.

Comment: will i have to make head as a global

Comment: what about printList fuction?

Comment: @dexter `printList` has a single asterisk, because it reads the list, never writes it. You do not have to make `head` global - you would be passing it to the function in the same way, without the `&` operator, and assign the result back to `head`. Both APIs let you create as many lists as you'd like.

Comment: i have made all changes as u told, and my code is comiped fine but i am not getting any output

Comment: @dexter - OK, time to get out your debugger.

Comment: i have now edited my question, please point out the mistake in the second code

Comment: @dexter That's because you are passing double-pointers to functions expecting a single pointer (e.g. `head=push(&head, 7);` should be `head=push(head, 7);` with no ampersand).

Answer (score 2):

Replace (&head,6) with (head,6).As you are not passing the address of the head, on receiving end you have push(struct node* head, int new_data).Rest all have been clarified by above given answer

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to create an empty node called `head`, and then create a pointer to that node called `list`. You can then pass `list` to all of the functions, like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void push(struct node *list, int new_data)
{
    struct node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->data = new_data;
    new_node->next = list->next;
    list->next = new_node;
}

void append(struct node *list, int new_data)
{
    while ( list->next != NULL ) 
        list = list->next;
    push( list, new_data );
}

void printList(struct node *node)
{
    for ( node=node->next; node != NULL; node=node->next )
        printf(" %d ", node->data);
    printf( "\n" );
}

int main( void )
{
    struct node head = { 0, NULL };
    struct node *list = &head;

    append(list, 6);
    push(list, 7);
    push(list, 1);
    append(list, 4);
    printf("\n Created Linked list is: ");
    printList(list);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```