# Why are my pointers locked within a scope?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, data-structures, linked-list

**The *pop function* that seems to always segfault.**

When I pass the pointer variables to my preceding functions, the functions operate accordingly and "seem" to store the data in success. But, with a closer inspection, the data is lost and/or corrupted. Even a simple thing such as initializing one of the Stack variables to NULL seems to fail.

I know that the stack is allocated correctly. I know that the data is being stored now, but with a caveat. I have to pass back the head pointer to the Stack that I just created (I do NOT like this method BTW).

```
operators = stack_operators(Token *object);
```

This causes further issues and complications that I would rather just avoid.

```
if (NULL == (operator = stack_operators(&tree)))
{//this code works and succeeds
    puts("failed to stack operators.");
    puts("committing suicide now.");
    break;
}

print_stack(operator);//prints malloc()d stack to screen
```

This same issue is affecting my `pop()` function. The irony is that I succeed in freeing the allocated Stack node, but my program refuses to shift the next node to the previous node and thus SIGSEGV error! This causes a double free or corruption error to occur.

*What concept am I overlooking and how do avoid these types of mistakes in the future?*

**The Pop Driver Program**

*This program recreates my issue without causing a Segmentation Fault at line #143. Lines 136 and 140 are where the data loss occurs. This occurs in my actual program with a SIGSEGV event causing a Double Free SIGSEGV event.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/* the Stack structure */
typedef struct stack_t {
    int object;
    struct stack_t * next;
} Stack;

typedef enum precedence_t { none, low, mid, hi } Precedence;  

//pop an item off of the stack
int pop(Stack * stack, int position);
//make a stack for the pop and push functions
Stack * stack_operators(const char ** tree, const int size);
Stack * stack_digits(const char ** tree, const int size);
//print tokens and stacks to screen
void print_token(const char ** tree, const int size);
void print_stack(Stack * stack);

//the token tree
const int SIZE = 4;

const char * data[5] = {
    "-",
    "123",
    "+",
    "54"
};

int main(void)
{
    Stack * digits = NULL, * operators = NULL;
    int value = 0;

    puts("Token List Value...");
    print_token(data, SIZE);

    puts("Converting token list to stack type...");
    puts("making digit stack...");
    digits = stack_digits(data, SIZE);

    puts("printing digit stack to screen:");
    print_stack(digits);

    puts("making operator stack...");
    operators = stack_operators(data, SIZE);

    puts("printing operator stack to screen:");
    print_stack(operators);

    puts("popping digits at position 0...");
    value = pop(digits, 0);
    printf("value = %d\n", value);

    puts("popping digits at position 0...");
    value = pop(digits, 0);
    printf("value = %d\n", value);

    puts("popping digits at position 0...");
    value = pop(digits, 0);//this is where the problem occurs
    printf("value = %d\n", value);

    return(0);
}

void print_token(const char ** tree, const int size)
{//print tokens to screen
    if (0 == size)
    {
        printf("the token tree has nothing to print.");
    }

    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        printf("token %0d: '%s'\n", (count + 1), tree[count]); 
    }

    putchar('\n');
}

void print_stack(Stack * stack)
{//print stack values to screen
    Stack * head = stack;

    if (NULL == stack)
    {
        puts("nothing in the stack to print.");
    }

    for (int i = 0; NULL != stack; i++)
    {
        if (ispunct(stack->object))
        {
            printf("stack: %d | value: '%c'\n", i, stack->object);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("stack: %d | value: '%d'\n", i, stack->object);
        }

        stack = stack->next;
    }

    stack = head;

    putchar('\n');
}

//Stack is the stack structure
//position is the location of the element to be popped
int pop(Stack * stack, const int position)
{//pop an object from the stack, free it, and return the its value
    int pos;
    int data = 0;
    Stack * previous = NULL;
    Stack * dump = NULL;
    Stack * head = stack;

    for (pos = 0; NULL != stack; pos++)
    {   
        if (pos != position)
        {
            previous = stack;
            stack = stack->next;
            continue;
        }

        data = stack->object;
        dump = stack;

        if (NULL == previous)
        {//first object on the stack
            stack = stack->next;//this line is supposed to cause a SEGFAULT
        }
        else
        {
            previous->next = stack->next; //stack does not retain pointer value
        }

        free(dump);//same stack is attempted to be freed, double free SIGSEGV

        break;      
    }

    if (0 < pos) { stack = head; }

    return data;
}

static Precedence token_precedence(char operator)
{//returns operator precedence
    switch (operator)
    {
        case '*':
        case '/':
            return mid; 
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return low;
        default:
            return none;
    }
}

//determines whether operator is unary or not
static bool isunary(const char ** token, int position)
{   //do NOT allow more than 2 consecutive + or - tokens
    //if there are, consider it to be a violation
    //if the last token is an operator, consider it to be a violation
    int previous = position - 1;
    Precedence precedence;

    if (0 == position)
    {
        if ('-' == token[position][0])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (previous <= 0) 
    {//too early to scan backwards
        return false;
    }

    precedence = token_precedence(token[previous][0]);

    if (low == precedence || mid == precedence)
    {
        if ('-' == token[position][0])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

//makes a stack for the given operators
Stack * stack_operators(const char ** tree, const int size)
{//initialize each stack with a value to be processed
    Stack * previous, * current, * head = NULL;

    for (int leaf = 0; leaf < size; leaf++)
    {
        if (!ispunct(tree[leaf][0]))
        {   
            continue;
        }

        if (isunary(tree, leaf))
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (NULL == (current = malloc(sizeof(Stack))))
        {//failed to allocate memory for the stack
            return NULL;
        }

        if (NULL == head)
        {//point to the head of the linked list
            head = current;
        }
        else
        {
            previous->next = current;
        }

        current->next = NULL;
        current->object = tree[leaf][0];
        previous = current;
    }

    return head;
}

//makes a stack for the given digits
Stack * stack_digits(const char ** tree, const int size)
{//initialize each stack with a value to be processed
    Stack * previous, * current, * head = NULL;

    for (int leaf = 0; leaf < size; leaf++)
    {
        if (ispunct(tree[leaf][0]))
        {
            if (!isunary(tree, leaf))
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        if (NULL == (current = malloc(sizeof(Stack))))
        {//failed to allocate memory for the stack
            return NULL;
        }

        if (NULL == head)
        {
            head = current;
        }
        else
        {
            previous->next = current;
        }

        if (isunary(tree, leaf))
        {
            ++leaf;
            current->object = -(atoi(tree[leaf]));
        }
        else
        {
            current->object = atoi(tree[leaf]);
        }

        current->next = NULL;
        previous = current;
    }

    return head;
}
```

What makes me believe that this is weird, is that I was under the impression that pointers were supposed to allow me "bend" the scope of a particular value so that I can ultimately alter or affect it somehow.

What's interesting with the code snippet below is that the `stack->next->object` is NOT null and supposedly assigns the next pointer to the current stack item, but fails to do so. Why is this happening?

```
if (NULL == previous)
{//first object on the stack
    puts("in pop(), previous IS null...");
    if (NULL == stack->next)
    {
        puts("next stack IS null...");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("stack next object: %d\n", stack->next->object);
    }
    stack = stack->next;
}
```

*Is this why programmers will usually use an Item like structure type and wrap it within a Node type structure that represents the linked list?*

Comment: Can you please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You are passing a pointer to a function, modifying the pointer and expecting that pointer value to propagate back to the caller. This is an incorrect understanding of function parameter passing. If you want to change the original pointer you need to pass in a parameter of type `Stack **` not `Stack *` to the `pop` function.

Comment: Fundamentally, you've forgotten or not realized that for a function to change the pointers stored in a calling function, you have to pass a pointer to a pointer to the function.  Or return the new head from the called function.  This is a very common problem with linked lists; there was at least one question where this was the basic diagnosis yesterday, and there must be many such questions on SO (hundreds is probably not an exaggeration).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010856/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    if (0 < pos) { stack = head; }
```

This line at the end of the function actually doesn't do much. You pass in the pointer to the data as `stack`, but in C, this pointer itself is copied by value. This means that while the data points to the same spot, the pointer itself is something different. At the end of the function, you modify this copied value, and the change is lost when you return from the function. If you want to modify the pointer, you have to pass in a pointer TO that pointer, like `Stack **stack`, and then modify it with

```
    if (0 < pos) { *stack = head; }
```

Remember, everything in C is passed by value, so if you want to modify anything, including pointers, use pointers that point to those values.

I'm not really sure if this answers your question, but that line specifically doesn't seem to do much.

Comment: That is the root cause of the problem; passing a pointer alone doesn't allow you to change the pointer in the calling function — you have to pass a pointer to the pointer, or otherwise evade the problem.

Comment: it does and it doesnt (answer my question). ill have to review my pointers chapter most likely. I don't remember reading that bit in my book though. could you cite this so I can use that as a reference? a link that explains why I would need a pointer to a pointer to affect the residual value for instance?

Comment: Just think of it in this manner: To modify anything in C, you need to 'know' its address, but everything is passed by value, e.g. the value is copied into a new variable and that's where pointers come in. The pointer you pass contains an address that points to the value you want to modify. In your case you want to modify a pointer (the value), so you need to pass in a pointer to it, a `Stack**`. If you wanted to modify THAT pointer, you'd use `Stack***`, and so on.

Comment: thank you for extended explanation, I'm starting to get a better picture of it now. I found a few posts w similar answers as well thanks to the links provided above.

Answer (score 3):

Given your `Stack` type, your push and pop functions could be:

```
void push(Stack **s, int value)
{
    assert(s != 0);
    Stack *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node == 0) { …handle memory allocation error… }
    node->next = *s;
    node->object = value;
    *s = node;
}

bool pop(Stack **s, int *value)
{
    assert(s != 0 && value != 0);
    if (*s == 0)
        return false;
    else
    {
        Stack *node = *s;
        *s = node->next;
        *value = node->object;
        free(node);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then in `main()`, you could use:

```
Stack *operands = 0;
push(&operands, 123);
push(&operands, 456);
push(&operands, 789);

int value;
while (pop(&operands, &value))
    printf("Popped: %d\n", value);
return(0);
```

Putting that all together into an executable, I get:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* For header */
typedef struct Stack Stack;

void push(Stack **s, int value);
bool pop(Stack **s, int *value);

/* Implementation only */
struct Stack
{
    int object;
    Stack *next;
};

void push(Stack **s, int value)
{
    assert(s != 0);
    Stack *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    node->next = *s;
    node->object = value;
    *s = node;
}

bool pop(Stack **s, int *value)
{
    assert(s != 0 && value != 0);
    if (*s == 0)
        return false;
    else
    {
        Stack *node = *s;
        *s = node->next;
        *value = node->object;
        free(node);
        return true;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Stack *operands = 0;

    push(&operands, 123);
    push(&operands, 456);
    push(&operands, 789);

    int value;
    while (pop(&operands, &value))
        printf("Popped: %d\n", value);

    return(0);
}
```

The output from running that is:

```
Popped: 789
Popped: 456
Popped: 123
```

Running it under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) gives it a clean bill of health too.  There are other methods of handling the out of memory condition.

You might also notice that the header that describes the stack interface does not need the details of the structure type; that can remain hidden for the implementation to know about (only).  This is a form of encapsulation.  You could split the sample code into three files: `stack.h` containing the `typedef` and two function declarations; `stack.c` including `stack.h` and containing just the two function definitions; and `main.c` including `stack.h` and containing just the `main()` function.